(How) can I set source path (in debuginfo) when building debian package
I need debuginfo for some libraries, for example gstreamer (which are not available in debian repo), but can be built using source packages. However it turns out that the source paths in the debug info is something like ../gst/gsttask.c that is relative to the build-dir. I could perhaps point out the build dir in gdb, but if I do this with a few libraries it becomes a bit unpractical.
Is there a way to specify that the source paths should be recorded relative to another location instead (or otherwise transform them) so that it would become more practical to get access to the source code in gdb?

Would it not be easier to configure your source path in gdb?

@StephenKitt For one built library maybe or two perhaps, but at some point it becomes rather messy i thing. And not to mention the possibility that two library happens to have source files named the same.

Ah right, I guess that’s what you were referring to with “I could perhaps point out the build dir in gdb, but if I do this with a few libraries it becomes a bit unpractical.”
